# setting ranges using 'Set' in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

Using this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select), i've been trying to get the following code to work.

```
' inserting formulas into the userOutput.csv sheet
    Dim wsUser As Worksheet:                Set wsUser = Worksheets("userOutput.csv")
    Dim agentEmailRange As Range:       'Set agentEmailRange = wsUser.Range(Cells(2, agentEmailColumn), Cells(propertyRows, agentEmailColumn))

     ' following line fails with runtime error 1004, method 'range' of object '_Worksheet' fialed.
     Set agentEmailRange = wsUser.Range(Cells(2, agentEmailColumn), Cells(propertyRows, agentEmailColumn))


            wsUser.Range("I1") = "Agent Email"

            With agentEmailRange
                .Value = "VLOOKUP(RC[-1], 'agentsOutput.csv'!R2C1:R" & agentRows & "C6 ,4, FALSE)"
            End With
```

the odd thing is it works one time.  When I change one of the variables, however, it begins to fail.

How do I get that formula in the cells I need on a dynamic basis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
Dim wsUser As Worksheet
Dim agentEmailRange As Range

Set wsUser = Worksheets("userOutput.csv")

With wsUser
    Set agentEmailRange = .Range(.Cells(2, agentEmailColumn), .Cells(propertyRows, agentEmailColumn))
    .Range("I1") = "Agent Email"
End With

agentEmailRange.Formula = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1], 'agentsOutput.csv'!R2C1:R" & agentRows & "C6 ,4, FALSE)"
```

You should fully qualify your `Cells`, i.e. specify to which sheet `Cells` belongs. Note that I'm using `.Cells(..)` instead `Cells(..)` - in that case Excel knows, that `Cells` belongs to sheet `wsUser`.